# AWS.Transfer is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm setting up a SFTP process using AWS Transfer for SFTP API in Lambda. I've followed the example in the documentation and the limited examples I've found online, but only receive the "AWS.Transfer is not a constructor" error message. Here's a simple example:

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

const transfer = new AWS.Transfer({
    apiVersion: '2018-11-05',
    region: `us-west-2`
});

const params = {
    ServerId: 'hlaoslloesses' /* required */
};

transfer.describeServer(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

The error message:

```html
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "AWS.Transfer is not a constructor",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Module._compile (module.js:652:30)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:565:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)",
    "Module.require (module.js:596:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:11:18)"
  ]
}

Request ID:
"ced0c74a-d81a-42b0-94a1-3e667921f7c4"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: ced0c74a-d81a-42b0-94a1-3e667921f7c4 Version: $LATEST
module initialization error: TypeError
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
END RequestId: ced0c74a-d81a-42b0-94a1-3e667921f7c4
REPORT RequestId: ced0c74a-d81a-42b0-94a1-3e667921f7c4 Duration: 79.81 ms Billed Duration: 100 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 67 MB 
module initialization error
TypeError
```

I've tried modifying the example from the API and the [SDK docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Transfer.html#createServer-property), but still get the same result. Has anyone gotten this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Transfer is relatively new.  The Node 8.10 Lambda runtime is running version 2.290.0 of the SDK, which doesn't include AWS.Transfer.

You can either deploy your function on the Node10.x runtime, which currently runs 2.437.0, or package a newer version of the JS SDK along with your function code.

Here's a link for future reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html

Comment: Thank you. Changing the runtime version resolved my issue.